# How to update object values with array variables? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object variable storing bar chart values and a button to update those values:

```js
 var config = {
       type: 'bar',
       data: {
       datasets: [{
       type: 'bar', label: 'Dataset 1',
       data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,       
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}};
                                        
document.getElementById('add5').addEventListener('click', function() {
 tnow = moment().format('HH');
 switch (tnow) {
    case'8':  config.data.datasets[0].data[0]  += 5; break;
    case'9':  config.data.datasets[0].data[1]  += 5; break;
    // ...
    case'23': config.data.datasets[0].data[15] += 5; break;
    case'24': config.data.datasets[0].data[16] += 5; break;
    default: alert('doot');}
 window.myLine.update()});
```

```html
   <button id="add5">+5</button>
```

I seek to store the value pointer as a variable to shorten the code. Tried

```
var h = [];
var h = config.data.datasets[0].data.slice();
```

but

```
case '23': h[15] += 5; break;
```

does not update the bar chart value. `alert(h[15])` does, however, return the accurate chart value.

How can I update the chart values using array variables?

---

**FULL CONTEXT:**

Using moment.js and chart.js to generate a bar graph that updates a value according to a real-time clock. Ex: if it's 7:30PM, clicking '+5' will add 5 to the bar located at 7PM. `case '8'` = 8AM, `case '23'` = 11PM, etc. I intend to add a second dataset which gets displayed when values exceed 60, using an `if` to modify the second dataset's value ( involving `config.data …` twice more - making the code pretty lengthy).

Comment: `datasheets != datasets`. Is that a typo in question or part of the problem?

Comment: Typo - corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `slice()`:

```
var h = config.data.datasets[0].data.slice();
```

you are making a *copy* of `config.data.datasets[0].data`. You then alter that copy in your code, but this has no effect on the bar chart because it doesn't change the original data:

```js
let datasets = [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}]
let h = datasets[0].data.slice()

h[0] ="What?"
console.log(h)                      // h has changed
console.log(datasets[0].data)       // original data is unchanged

console.log(h === datasets[0].data) // because they are not the same array
```

If you want to shorten your code, just take a reference to the array without `slice()`:

```
var h = config.data.datasets[0].data
```

```js
let datasets = [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}]
let h = datasets[0].data

h[0] ="What?"
console.log(h)                      // h has changed
console.log(datasets[0].data)       // original data is also chaged

console.log(h === datasets[0].data) // because they ARE the same array
```

Comment: I tried EXACTLY this prior to the slice method, and it didn't work - now tried again and it works. Visual Studio must be drunk. 

Regardless, thanks for the response.